# Can not move wordpress site to new folder

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu, nginx

Ubuntu server 18, nginx 1.15, php-fpm, mysql.

1) Moved WordPress `site.com` from `folder1` to `folder2`.

2) Change the root dir for `site.com` from `/var/www/html/folder1` to `folder2` in `nginx` config.

3) `nginx restart`

As result of seeing a white screen instead of `site.com`
But! `wp-login` page works and after signing in as admin - site shows up. No problems. Sign out - watch white screen again.

What am I doing wrong?

Tried to search and replace links in the database from `folder1` to `folder2` with no luck.

Comment: Please follow this link https://thethemefoundry.com/blog/wordpress-white-screen-of-death/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Wordpress `Dashboard`, `Settings`, go to `Permalinks` and save the configuration.

It should solve your white screen problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check .htaccess (path needs to be correct), wp-config.php (maybe path is defined there) and check if you have cache folder in wp-content (especially if you see site as logged in user).